# Select only lines that touch both sides of polygon - PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon, select, linestring

I want to select lines that only touch both sides of a polygon. Is there a function in postgis that can do this? See image below. I only want to select lines from the circle on the left where the line touches both sides of the polygon.

[image]

Comment: Is it right to say that both the start point and the end point of the line must touch the outer ring of the polygon?

Comment: and the line must be otherwise totally inside the polygon?

Comment: so that ST_Split https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Split.html "split polygon by line" creates two polygons and "split line by polygon" does not split the line

Comment: ...and the larger of both possible great circle segments between start/end points does not intersect the interior?

Answer (score 4):

I would say that to fit your description, the line should be :

- Completely inside the polygon
- Have its start and end points touching the boundary of the polygon

```
SELECT line_id, geom
FROM line a
JOIN polygon b ON ST_Within(a.geom,b.geom)
AND ST_Intersects(ST_StartPoint(a.geom),ST_Boundary(b.geom))
AND ST_Intersects(ST_EndPoint(a.geom),ST_Boundary(b.geom))
```

Comment: The ST_Intersects relationship may not find all points which are "on" a line. Using ST_DWithin with a small tolerance will be more reliable.

Comment: I think, a combination of st_contains (https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html) and st_touches (https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Touches.html) will do the job